# Script execution time for import time --> What units are the results in?

Tags: python, time, subtraction, execute

I'm using `import time` module to calculate how long each run of my while loop took to execute.

The code is below:

```
while (...):
   start = time.time()

   ...code here

   end = time.time()
   
   print (f"python loop execution total time {end-start}")
```

The code above returns me: "python loop execution total time 2.3876123428344727"

Is this 2.3876123428344727 value in seconds or milliseconds or something else?  I guess what I am asking is what unit of time the code returns.

Comment: Can you do an experiment to calibrate the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/time.html#time.time):

> Return the time *in seconds* since the epoch as a floating point number.

Comment: so to confirm, the loop ran in 2.3876123428344727 seconds, correct?

Comment: @PineNuts0, also, you could use [`perf_counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) for maximum precision

Comment: PLEASE Understand, however, that most of those digits are fiction.  Your PC can't measure time much below a microsecond (2.387612), and even that is not going to be repeatable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes time.time() returns number of seconds in a floating point.

To elaborate, time.time() returns the current timestamp.
Timestamp is the exact number of seconds that have passed since unix time beginning, i.e., January 1st 00:00 1970.

If you want to find out the time taken by a code snippet to execute, what you are doing isn't exactly wrong but there are other ways to find the time taken by a code to execute which are much more standardized, for instance, the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module.

But for simple use cases your method should be good enough.